# KNN Classifier for simple digit recognition

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-recognition

Actually , i have an assignment where it is required to recognize individual decimal digits as a part of the text recognition process.I am already given a set of JPEG formatted images of some digits. Each image is of size 160 x 160 pixels.After checking some resources here i managed to write this code but :

1)I am not sure if reading the images and resizing them in matrices for holding them is right or not.

2)Supposing that i have 30 train data images for numbers [0-9] each number has three images and i have 10 images for test each image is of only one digit.How to calculate distance between every test and train in a loop ? Because in my part of code for calculating Euclidean it gives an output zero.

3)How to calculate accuracy by using confusion matrix ?

```
% number of train data
Train = 30;
%number of test data
Test =10;
% to store my images
tData = uint8(zeros(160,160,30));
tTest = uint8(zeros(160,160,10));


for k=1:Test 
  s1='im-';
  s2=num2str(k);
  t = strcat('testy/im-',num2str(k),'.jpg'); 
  im=rgb2gray(imread(t));
  I=imresize(im,[160 160]);
  tTest(:,:,k)=I;


  %case testing if it belongs to zero     

  for l=1:3

   ss1='zero-';
   ss2=num2str(l);
   t1 = strcat('data/zero-',num2str(l),'.jpg'); 
   im1=rgb2gray(imread(t1));

   I1=imresize(im1,[160 160]);
   tData(:,:,l)=I1;

  % Euclidean distance 
 distance= sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, tData(:,:,k), tTest(:,:,l)).^2, 2));
   [d,index] = sort(distance);
  %k=3
   % index_close(l) = index(l:3);
   %x_close = I(index_close,:);

  end      
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all i think 10 test data is not enough.
Just use the below function, data_test is your training data() and data_label is their labels. re size your images to smaller sizes!
I think the default distance measure is Euclidean distance but you can choose other ways such as City-block method for example.

```
Class = knnclassify(data_test, data_train, lab_train, 11);
fprintf('11-NN Accuracy: %f\n', sum(Class == lab_test')/length(lab_test));


Class = knnclassify(data_test, data_train, lab_train, 1, 'cityblock');
fprintf('1-NN Accuracy (cityblock): %f\n', sum(Class == lab_test')/length(lab_test));
```

Ok now you have the overall accuracy but this is not a good measure, it's better to calculate the accuracy separately for each class and then calculate their mean.
you can calculate a specific class (id) accuracy like this,,

```
    idLocations = (lab_test == id);
    NumberOfId = sum(idLocations); 
    NumberOfCurrect =sum (lab_test (idLocations) == Class(idLocations));
    NumberOfCurrect/NumberOfId %Class id accuracy
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i just wanted to make it without using Knnclassify also, how can i resize my images into smaller ones and what are lab_train or lab_test ?

Answer (score 0):

as your questions are:

1) image re-sizing does affects the accuracy of the whole process.
Ans: As you mentioned in your question your images are already of the size 160 by 160, `imresize` will not affect it, but if your image is too small in size say 60*60 it will perform interpolation to increase the spatial dimensions of the image, which may affects structure and shape of the digit, to tackle these kind of variability, your training data should have much more samples(at least 50 samples per class), and some pre-processing should be apply on data like de-skewing of the digit image.

2) euclidean distance is good measure but not the best to deal with these kind of problems, as its distribution is a spherical distribution it may give same distance for to different digits. if you are working in MATLAB beware of of variable casting, you are taking difference so both the variable should be double in nature. it may be one of the reason of wrong distance calculation. in this line `distance= sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, tData(:,:,k), tTest(:,:,l)).^2, 2));` you are summing matrices column wise so output of this will be a row vector(1 X 160) which have sum along each corner. i think it should be like this:`distance= sqrt(sum(sum(bsxfun(@minus, tData(:,:,k), tTest(:,:,l)).^2, 2)));` i have just added one more sum there for getting sum of differences for whole matrix try it whether it helps or not.

3) For checking accuracy of your classifier precisely you have to have a large training dataset,by the way, Confusion matrix created during the process of cross-validation, where you split your training data into training samples and testing samples, so you know output classes in both the sample, now perform classification process, prepare a matrix for num_classe X num_classes(in your case 10 X 10), where rows resembles actual classes and columns belongs to prediction. take a sample from test and predict output class, suppose your classifier predict 5 and sample's actual class is also 5 put +1 in the confusion_matrix(5,5); if your classifier have predicted it as 3, you should do +1 at confusion_matrix(5,3). finally add diagonal elements of the confusion_mat and divide it by the total number of the test samples. output will be accuracy of your classifier.

P.S. Try to have atleast 50 samples per class and during cross-validation divide the training data 85:10 ratio where 90% sample should be used for training and rest 10 % should be used for testing the classifier.

Hope it have helps you.
feel free to share your thoughts.

Thank You